# Can't execute SharePoint BCS AssociationNavigator when my entity classes are in another assembly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, bcs

I have a simple SharePoint 2010 BCS solution where I define two entities and a simple parent-child relationship between them.  I happen to have entity classes (`Parent` and `Child`) in a separate assembly from my service classes (`ParentService` and `ChildService`). This doesn't seem to present a problem when using just Finder and SpecificFinder methods, but when I try to execute an AssociationNavigator method it fails.  When my entity types are in the same assembly as the BCS model definition and associates service classes, the AssociationNavigator works fine.  I am calling the AssociationNavigator like this:

```
var entity_instance_collection = new EntityInstanceCollection(1);
entity_instance_collection.Add(parent_entity_instance);
var association = (IAssociation)parent_entity.GetMethodInstance("ParentToChildAssociationNavigator", MethodInstanceType.AssociationNavigator);
var child_items = child_entity.FindAssociated(entity_instance_collection, association, lobi);
```

When the entity types are in a separate assembly, I get an InvalidMetadataObjectException when trying to execute `FindAssociated`:

> Cannot load Type described by TypeDescriptor TypeName
>   'BdcModelProject2.BdcModel1.Parent, BdcModel1' on Parameter with Name
>   'parent' on Method with Name 'ReadItem' on Entity (External Content
>   Type) with Name 'Parent' in Namespace 'BdcModelProject2.BdcModel1'.

with this InnerException:

> Could not load type 'BdcModelProject2.BdcModel1.Parent' from assembly
>   'BdcModelProject2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=50bc5a1f7318bdeb'.

So, it seems that my app is just trying to load my entity types from the assembly where the BCS model is defined (BdcModelProject2) rather than the assembly where my entities are actually defined (ClassLibrary1).  I have a few points of confusion about this:

1. I see that the BCS model has TypeName attributes in the TypeDescriptors that describe the types of the classes that implement the entity classes, but the Finder and SpecificFinder methods seem to function properly for me even when gibberish is supplied here, yet the AssociationNavigator fails to load the type. Why is this?
2. I don't see anywhere in the Visual Studio-generated bdcm file or in the MSDN docs for a [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558384.aspx) that indicates where an assembly name can be specified for the entity types.

So, how can I use entity types in my BCS project when those entities are defined in a different assembly?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here:

- It does not find the dll
- It finds an old version of the dll, that does not contain the new code that you are using

We have often had a problem that an old version is in the GAC. When a new version is installed in the bin directory, it just ignores it and continues using the version in the GAC. Then you delete the version in the GAC, but it still does not work, since it has cached the old version. Finally an IIS reset or a machine restart gets it working.

Short answer: Try and find an old version of the dll on the machine.

**Edit**

You could use a tool like **Assembly Binding Log Viewer** to track down the problem.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: But these types were not *ever* in the bdc assembly, and they will not ever be in the bdc assembly.  I am sure that the types are in the assembly in the GAC that I want to use as the source for the types, but my app just never looks there. I think I want to know really how SharePoint decides which types to look for.

Comment: Where are you deploying BdcModelProject2 to?

Comment: Everything is going to the GAC, and I have verified that the appropriately named entity model types are in the GAC'ed version of the assembly.

Comment: Just to make sure try an IIS reset

Comment: Also are you using a sandboxed solution?

Comment: Yep.  This is on my desktop dev server.  One server for everything.

Comment: Just to cover all the possibilities, the types are not marked as Internal?